# SVG path with image filter but transparent background

Tags: image, svg, svg-filters

I have a path with an image which is added through a filter.
Also the path has a background colour set like this:

`myPath.css('fill', bgColour);`

My question is how it is possible to have the path transparent but keep the image visible?

I tried `fill: transparent`, `fill-opacity: 0`, `fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)` but with these the image becomes invisible, too.

Here is my current code:

```
var filter = svg.filter(defs, 'myFilter', 0, 0, '100%', '100%', filterOptions);

var sourcePathRef = 'SourceGraphic';
if (hasTransparentBackground()) {
    // make path transparent
    svg.filters.colorMatrix(filter, 'TransformedGraphic', sourcePathRef, 'matrix', [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]);
    sourcePathRef = 'TransformedGraphic';
}

// add the image
var outputSlot = 'customImage';
svg.filters.image(filter, outputSlot, imageFile, {
    preserveAspectRatio: aspectRatio
});
// move it
svg.filters.offset(filter, 'movedImage', outputSlot, moveX, moveY);
// combine image with path for clipping
svg.filters.composite(filter, 'clip', 'in', 'movedImage', sourcePathRef);
// mix both images
svg.filters.blend(filter, '', 'normal', 'clip', sourcePathRef);
// apply the filter
imageSlot.attr('filter', 'url(#myFilter)');
```

Comment: What does it mean for the path to be transparent but the image visible?

Comment: If the image is smaller than the path, then the remaining regions of the path should not be filled with a colour, but show what is behind the SVG file (for example a background image).

Comment: Why not draw an image as an image directly and just clip it to a path then?

Comment: You mean `clip-path`? Because this is not supported by the Microsoft browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: That's talking about a CSS clip path, not an SVG clip path. IE9+ supports SVG clip-paths on SVG content.

Comment: You can do this within the filter - just add a feColorMatrix to dial down opacity before you bring in the image (presumably with feImage?). But it would help if you posted the code,

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried the feColorMatrix approach, but it seems the image becomes invisible, too. Maybe I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Added the current code to the original question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix: skip the last (blend) filter :-)